# ubuntu running Xampp with MySql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, xampp

For my study I've been working with MySql and php for a while.
Now I'm trying to set up a side project to keep myself entertained during the holidays.
For this I am collaborating with a friend and this leads to my problem.

The problem:
we've already had our code setup to work with a MySQL database, now apparently the newest xampp releases, at least for linux, come with mariaDB instead of the old MySQL.

Now I can install a mysql server just fine. But I can't seem to figure out how Xampp is configured, and where I can have it start MySQL as the db.

I've tried googling it, but sadly a lot of answers are either for windows or have been removed.
during this process I also found a lot of reasons to use mariaDB over MySQL, and although I will look in to this in the future I would prefer to learn how to edit/change the xampp config. (both for the ease of programming atm, and the learning experience with xampp's config).

So, in conslusion: if someone could point me in the right direction or give me some pointers as to how I can start xampp with MySQL I would be very grateful.

Kind regards,
Daneel

Comment: For what it's worth, MariaDB is a fork of MySQL. It's almost completely compatible. Some say it's better, evidently including the XAMPP team.  It's worth trying your project with it before abandoning XAMPP and installing its components individually.

Comment: maybe I should have been a bit more clear, I do intend to look into switching it up at a later date. For now my interest is about 30% convenience and 70% understanding how Xampp works. I don't mean to abandon Xampp, merely have it work with the mysql for now. since from what I've gathered it should still be possible.

Comment: My point is this: MariaDB *is* MySQL.

Comment: Well, guess I'll have some reading to do then. Thanks for the extra clarification! I'll post an update later. (Altho this does explain why there is/was so little information about running XAMPP with MySQL)

As a last question for now. Do you know where I could read a bit more about _why_ they decided to switch to MariaDB, and what the main differences are.


Edit: and if you could post your original explenation as an answer I can mark it as the answer, might help someone else in the future as well (: